# Start and Stop script of ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, openstack

I have a script (**twoRules.sh**) which add rules to ovs plugin bridge.

The rules gets deleted when someone does `service neutron-plugin-openvswitch-agent restart` or reboots the system. So where should I put my scripts so that after the **restart** of **neutron-plugin-openvswitch-agent** the (**twoRules.sh**) scripts get executed successfully and rules remain added.

I tried putting it in `/etc/init.d/neutron-plugin-openvswitch-agent` file as other people suggested but this file is only called on `/etc/init.d/neutron-plugin-openvswitch-agent restart` and not on service neutron-plugin-openvswitch-agent restart.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the script to a a SysV-style init script. There are many documents out there explaining about this.

http://www.debian-administration.org/article/28/Making_scripts_run_at_boot_time_with_Debian
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-controlling-access-to-linux-services.html
https://wiki.debian.org/Daemon

This way you can configure the script to be executed after certain services start or stop or when runlevel changes.

Comment: That is OK that I have to convert it to SysV-style init script but how will it be dependent on the start and stop of neutron-plugin-openvswitch-agent sevice

Comment: Just read the linked docs. Convert your script, install it in `/etc/rc.d/`, then create the appropriate symlinks `/etc/rc[n].d/` as described.

Comment: Do you mean to convert the original script?? I don't know the binary of neutron-plugin-openvswitch-agent. That is why I am trying to do it as an add up to the main script